# WordPress PaidMembershipsPro track day of the membership

Tags: php, wordpress

I was looking for a plugin that allowed only paid members to access certain WP pages and to display the content based on their day of the course (the course is 200 days long). I used PaidMembershipsPro, but I had to modify it to my needs and I post it here in case might be useful for someone else.

If someone buys a different "membership level" it extends it instead of overwriting (I had to make 3 levels for 3 payment plans, 1/3/6 months, I named them all the same but if someone buys 3 months and then another month it reset the duration, so there is a filter for it below). I asked on SO already, but I didn't get an answer, so I wrote the functions myself. It might be bit sloppy though.

Comment: What's your question exactly? If you're looking for someone to review your code might I suggest http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I added that in Q&A form. I was looking all over the internet and I didn't find a solution, so I spent some time and did it myself and posted it in case someone wants to do something similar (might not happen, but just in case).

Comment: Ah, roger! A tip for next time; you can answer your own question while your still writing it. May help prevent confusion next time :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I checked the box "answer your own question Q&A style" and another field showed up which posted the answer straight away below my question. I wasn't sure if that's how it's meant to be done, so I just wrote it there :P

Comment: Ah right, then it's my fault! I was in the review section (it only shows a question or answer), so your answer didn't actually show up for me. Therefor my comments. Apologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the table:

```
tt_subs s_id(int) s_user(int) s_months(int) s_since(timestamp)
```

This is the function that puts the data into a table (it takes the duration as days, because all my levels were timed in days)

```
add_action("pmpro_after_checkout", tt_AddToSubs);

 function tt_AddToSubs($user_id){ 
   global $wpdb, $current_user;
   $days = $current_user->data->membership_level->expiration_number; //get days from current order
   $months = ceil($days/30);
   $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('today midnight'));
   $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT s_user, s_months, s_since FROM tt_subs WHERE s_user = $user_id", ARRAY_A);
   $rowCount = $wpdb->num_rows;
   if($rowCount == 0)//if it's a new user
   {
     $wpdb->insert('tt_subs',array('s_user' => $user_id,
                   's_months' => $months,'s_since' => $today),
        array('%s','%d','%s')
    );
   }
   else
   {
     $sincedays = ($result[0]['s_months']*30); //counted without the new month
     $since = strtotime("-$sincedays days", strtotime('today midnight'));
     $newsince = (strtotime($result[0]['s_since']) <= $since ? $since : strtotime($result[0]['s_since'])); //if membership has passed, shift s_since so user is back in his day
     $newsince = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newsince);
     $months += $result[0]['s_months']; //add months to the existing ones

     $wpdb->update('tt_subs',
     array('s_months' => $months,'s_since' => $newsince),
     array( 's_user' => $user_id ), //where array(
        '%d',   // value1
        '%s'    // value2
     ),
     array( '%d' ) //where format
     );
   }
 }
```

this is a filter that I found for extending the memberships instead of overwriting them

```
add_filter("pmpro_checkout_level", "level_extend_memberships");

 function level_extend_memberships($level)
  {
  global $pmpro_msg, $pmpro_msgt, $current_user;
  //does this level expire? are they an existing members with an expiration date?
  if(!empty($level) && !empty($level->expiration_number) && pmpro_hasMembershipLevel() && !empty($current_user->membership_level->enddate))
  {
  //get the current enddate of their membership
  $expiration_date = $current_user->membership_level->enddate;
  //calculate days left
  $todays_date = time();
  $time_left = $expiration_date - $todays_date;
  //time left?
  if($time_left > 0)
  {
  //convert to days and add to the expiration date (assumes expiration was 1 year)
  $days_left = floor($time_left/(60*60*24));
  //figure out days based on period
  if($level->expiration_period == "Day")
  $total_days = $days_left + $level->expiration_number;
  elseif($level->expiration_period == "Week")
  $total_days = $days_left + $level->expiration_number * 7;
  elseif($level->expiration_period == "Month")
  $total_days = $days_left + $level->expiration_number * 30;
  elseif($level->expiration_period == "Year")
  $total_days = $days_left + $level->expiration_number * 365;
  //update number and period
  $level->expiration_number = $total_days;
  $level->expiration_period = "Day";
  }
  }
  return $level;
}
```

and finally a function that returns the day the user is on

```
function tt_myDay()
{
   global $wpdb;
   if(current_user_can('add_users'))
   {
     return 999;
   }
   else
   {
     $resultq = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT s_since, s_months FROM tt_subs WHERE s_user = ".get_current_user_id(), ARRAY_A);
     $day = ceil((time() - strtotime($resultq[0]['s_since']))/86400);
     return ($day > ($resultq[0]['s_months']*30) ? ($resultq[0]['s_months']*30) : $day );
   }
}
```